# How do I get two arrays in Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

JS CODE:

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: 'assignavailtrainers.php',
         data: {action:'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data) {

         }
 });
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    $username = "trainerapp";
    $password = "password";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $link = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    if(@mysql_select_db("trainer_registration"))
{

    $select_query_num = @mysql_query("select program_id,facilitator_id,availability_status from program_facilitator where availability_status in (1,2)");
    $select_query_name = @mysql_query("select facilitator_id,firstname,lastname,email_id from facilitator_details");
    $num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($select_query_num);
    $trainerdetails = [];
    $traineravaildetails = [];
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query_num))
    {

        $trainerdetails[$i]['pgidi'] = $row['program_id'];
        $trainerdetails[$i]['facilitatorid'] = $row['facilitator_id'];
        $trainerdetails[$i]['avail_status'] = $row['availability_status'];
        $trainerdetails[$i]['idi'] = $row['facilitator_id'];

        $i++;
    }


        while($row1 =@mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query_name))
    {
        $traineravaildetails[$j]['facilitatorid'] = $row1['facilitator_id'];
        $traineravaildetails[$j]['firstname'] = $row1['firstname'];
        $traineravaildetails[$j]['lastname'] = $row1['lastname'];
        $traineravaildetails[$j]['emailidvalue'] = $row1['email_id'];
        $j++;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('result1'=>$trainerdetails,'result2'=>$traineravaildetails));
}
?>
```

Please help me with the code in the ajax success function area. I've tried using initChart2 but I get an error which says initChart2 is not defined. I don't seem to understand of how to get two arrays from PHP in ajax since I'm a newbie ajax. If someone can help me with the code along with explanation, it'd be great. And I also need to know how to differentiate outputs in ajax which are sent from PHP.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions because they're deprecated for a long time and will be removed with PHP7 in some months. Use PDO or mysql**i** instead.

Comment: check response console.log(data.toSource());   Also set data type for ajax

Comment: I tried console.log(data.toSource()); before.. but didn't work.. any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

First one is to simply parse received (text) data to JSON:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
// or simply data = JSON.parse(data);
```

But the best one in my oppinion is to specify json dataType to the $.ajax() request:

```
$.ajax(
    data: {action:'test'},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

This way, $.ajax() will also check for the validity of the received JSON data and error callback will be called instead of success one in case of wrong JSON data received.

...also is important to note you missed to send the json content-type header in your php with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Sending this header the dataType: 'json' parameter is no longer (strictly) necessary because $.ajax() guesses it by default attending to the received content-type. But, personally, I prefer to do both.

See [$.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

… in your PHP.

While you are outputting JSON, you are telling the browser that it is HTML (which is the default for PHP) so jQuery isn't converting it to a useful data structure.

Add that and then you should be able to access `data.result1` and `data.result2`.

Answer (score 0):

To get ajax data:

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: 'assignavailtrainers.php',
         data: {action:'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data) {
           data.result1;
           data.result2;
         }
 });
```

You can use `console.log(data);` to view data structure